# Searching a full hash table

Tags: c, search, hash

Considering the following code snippet:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define TABLESIZE 100

sturct record{
       int k;
       int r;
       }table[TABLESIZE];

int tcount=0;

int search_and_insert(int key,int rec){
    int i;
    i=h(key);
    while(table[i].k!=key && table[i].k!=NULL)
                                              i=rh(i);

    if(table[i].key==NULL){
                           table[i].k=key;
                           table[i].r=rec;
                           tcount++;
                           }
    return i;
    }

int h(int key){

    return key%1000;

    } 

int rh(int hkey){

    int k;
    if(hkey==99)
    return 0;
    return ((hkey+1)%1000);

    }
```

The `while` loop maybe an infinite loop if the table is already full,to remedy this problem,I can
introduce an `if` statement like this:

```
   if(tcount<TABLESIZE){
    while(table[i].k!=key && table[i].k!=NULL)
                                              i=rh(i);/*Rehash*/

    if(table[i].key==NULL){
                           table[i].k=key;
                           table[i].r=rec;
                           tcount++;
                         }
}
```

But according to me this gives rise to another problem, i.e. I won't be able to search for a record which already exists in the table , when the table is full or the search will provide a wrong result.

Can this problem be resolved?

Comment: An `int` can never be `NULL`. You need a separate flag per bucket to indicate whether it's in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're doing simple linear probing, you can easily check whether you've gone full circle around the hash table by comparing the current hash value to the original one.

```
int h0 = hash(key);
int h = h0;

do {
    if (found_in_bucket(key, h))
        return value_in_bucket(h);
    h = rehash(h);
} while (h != h0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical solution to this sort of problem is chaining, which is to have your hash keys point to a linked structure:

```
struct h_value
{
  int rec;
  struct h_value *next;
};
```

When inserting, if you look up the location and rec is not what you're inserting you look through all the next pointer for rec and if you don't find it in the list make a new h_value and add it to the end. In the worst case you'll have a singly-linked list but in the typical case you'll evenly distribute your values among all the buckets.

If you know ahead of time your values you may want to look into perfect hashing, like [gperf](http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/).

Comment: gperf I think you mean... ;-)